# Spring Autowiring with Inheritance

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm relatively new to Spring, and I'm trying to understand an issue I'm experiencing in which a dependency is not being autowired into a bean that is the parent of another bean that is being constructed.

The parent class is specified as follows.  Note that I've abbreviated some of the logic for clarity.  The Log class is implemented as an entity.

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class AppTransaction {

    private String componentName;

    @Autowired
    private LogRepository logRepository;

    public AppTransaction(String componentName) {
        this.componentName = componentName;
    }

    public void writeLog(String logText) {
        Log log = new Log(this.componentName, logText);
        this.logRepository.save(log);
    }
}
```

The child class is implemented as follows.

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class EmployeeJobTransaction extends AppTransaction {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    private String componentName;
    private String jobName;

    public EmployeeJobTransaction(String componentName, String jobName) {
      super(componentName);
      this.jobName = jobName;
    }

    public List<String> doJob() {
      List<String> statuses = this.employeeRepository.getEmployeeJobStatuses();
      writeLog("Job complete.");
    }
}
```

In my service class, I'm using the application context to get an instance of the EmployeeJobTransaction bean.  I'm doing this because the input parameters to the EmployeeJobTransaction bean are based on user input.

```
@Service
public class JobServiceImpl {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public void initJob() {
      EmployeeJobTransaction employeeJobTransaction = this.applicationContext.getBean(EmployeeJobTransaction.class, "EmployeeComponent", "CheckEmployeeJobStatus");
      jobTransaction.doJob();
    }

}
```

When I get the EmployeeJobTransaction bean, the EmployeeRepository bean is autowired as expected.  However, the AppTransaction instance created does not appear to be a Spring-managed bean because the LogRepository object that has been autowired is null.  I'm assuming this is because the call to super() in the EmployeeJobTransaction class does not create an instance of AppTransaction as a Spring-managed bean.

What are my options?  Must I autowire the LogRepository bean into the EmployeeJobTransaction class and then pass it to the writeLog method as a parameter?  I'm not understanding why the parent class is not created as a Spring bean when the child class is created as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those that may come across this question in the future, I understand now that I was interpreting what Spring was doing incorrectly.

I turned on debugging and had set a breakpoint in the AppTransaction constructor.

```
public AppTransaction(String componentName) {
    this.componentName = componentName;  //Breakpoint here
}
```

When I executed my logic, I was confused because the autowired LogRepository bean was null.

According to the Spring documentation:

> Fields are injected right after construction of a bean, before any config methods are invoked.

Therefore, it makes sense that the LogRepository bean is null in the constructor.  When the writeLog method is called, the LogRepository bean is not null because it was successfully autowired AFTER the construction of the AppTransaction bean.

Thanks to those who responded.

**TLDR:** Autowired fields are null inside the constructor of a bean.  The beans are not autowired until the construction of the bean in which they are referenced has completed.

Comment: While you are on it: Maybe you want to switch to constructor injection. Field injection is a lot of reflection magic and hard to test without even more reflection magic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a littel confused. I will try to explain me:

Your code shows 3 Spring beans:

- AppTransaction

  - With an autowired dependency of the logRepository
- EmployeeJobTransaction

  - With an autowired dependency of the employeeRepository
  - With an autowired dependency of the logRepository (inhereted of the parent class AppTransaction)
- JobServiceImpl

When you call to he *super* method on EmployeeJobTransaction you are not calling to *AppTransaction* bean. You are calling to the parent class constructor method.

Is unnecessary to have a Spring bean of the AppTransaction class (remove the *Component* and *Scope* annotations of this class)

When you call to getBean method, Spring create a new bean each time. I think this is unnecessary. You could declare EmployeeJobTransaction bean as singleton (remove de Scope annotation) and to add the componentName and jobName attributes as parameters of *doJob* method.

I think woult be the best way.